# How to split string only on first whitespace in Ocaml

Tags: string, ocaml

How would we split string to string list in Ocaml, but only on first whitespace.
So for example: "Hello my dear friend" becomes ["Hello"; "my dear friend"]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `bounded_split` from the standard [Str](https://ocaml.org/releases/4.11/htmlman/libref/Str.html) library:

```
(* Compile with: ocamlfind ocamlc -o example -package str -linkpkg example.ml *)
let split_on_first_space =
  let re = Str.regexp "[ \t\r\n]" in
  function s -> Str.bounded_split re s 2

let _ =
  let str = "Hello my dear friend" in
  match split_on_first_space str with
  | [first; rest] ->
     Printf.printf "%s and %s\n" first rest
  | _ -> print_endline "No space in string!"
```

---

If using Jane Street's Base replacement standard library, its [String](https://ocaml.janestreet.com/ocaml-core/latest/doc/base/Base/String/index.html) module has `lsplit2_exn` and `lsplit2` for splitting a string into two on the first occurrence of a given character:

```
(* Compile with ocamlfind ocamlc -o example -package base,stdio -linkpkg example.ml *)
open Base

let _ =
  let str = "Hello my dear friend" in
  begin
    try
      let (first, rest) = String.lsplit2_exn ~on:' ' str in
      Stdio.printf "1: %s and %s\n" first rest;
    with Not_found_s _ -> Stdio.print_endline "1: No space in string!"
  end;
  match String.lsplit2 ~on:' ' str with
  | Some (first, rest) -> Stdio.printf "2: %s and %s\n" first rest
  | None -> Stdio.print_endline "2: No space in string!"
```

And of course you can easily implement `lsplit2` using the default standard library:

```
let lsplit2 str ~on =
  let open String in
  match index_opt str on with
  | Some pos -> Some (sub str 0 pos,
                      sub str (pos + 1) (length str - pos - 1))
  | None -> None
```